Añadir nuevo impuesto a los que tiene WooCommerce para determinados productos
Tengo un problema con los impuestos de WooCommerce.
Debo añadir un nuevo impuesto 8% antes del precio total a determinados productos solo a un rol específico, 'usuario_diferente'.
Otros productos, ya incluyen otros impuestos que se muestran antes del precio final, y luego se suman a este.
Es importante que este impuesto no afecte a el resto de impuesto o descuentos ya añadidos a WooCommerce.
<tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-impuesto-1">
<th>Impuesto</th>
<td data-title="Impuesto">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">2,20
<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
 </span>
 </td>
</tr>

He conseguido añadir con add_action el impuesto a los productos que necesito médiente su "ID", y funciona.
Pero se muestra en otra línea diferente:
<tr class="fee">
<th>Ajuste de impuestos adicionales</th>
<td data-title="Ajuste de impuestos adicionales">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
<bdi>0,38<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>
</bdi>
</span>
</td>
</tr>

¿cómo lo debo hacer para que este impuesto se sume a los que ya tengo de WooCommerce, en lugar de mostrarse en una nueva línea?
Hice varias pruebas, pero realmente estoy muy confusa con esto, no logro entender el funcionamiento de WooCommerce frente a los impuestos.
Podría añadir directamente una nueva tasa de impuestos en WooCommerce, pero al tratarse de únicamente, determinados productos, no puedo hacerlo y estoy bloqueada
Este es el resultado:

// Hook para modificar los impuestos en función de los productos y roles de usuario
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_tax_to_selected_products', 20, 1);

function add_custom_tax_to_selected_products($cart) {
    // Comprobar si es administrador o AJAX request, y evitar ejecutar el código en ese caso
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return;
    }

    // Verificar si el usuario tiene el rol 'usuario_diferente'
    if (!current_user_can('usuario_diferente')) {
        return;
    }

    // IDs de los productos que deben recibir el impuesto del 8%
    $product_ids_with_tax = array(355, 625); // Sustituir con los IDs reales de los productos

    // Variable para almacenar el total del impuesto adicional
    $tax_amount = 0;

    // Iterar sobre los productos en el carrito
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Comprobar si el producto está en la lista de productos con impuesto adicional
        if (in_array($product_id, $product_ids_with_tax)) {
            // Calcular el 8% del subtotal de este producto
            $item_total = $cart_item['line_total']; // Precio total del producto en el carrito sin impuestos
            $tax_amount += ($item_total * 0.08);    // Sumar el 8% del precio total de ese producto
        }
    }

     // Si hay un monto de impuesto a agregar, lo sumamos al total de impuestos
    if ($tax_amount > 0) {
         
        $cart->add_fee( __('Ajuste de impuestos adicionales', 'woocommerce'), $tax_amount, true, '' );
    } 
}

